# Using an undefined token as argument

Tags: macros, expansion, arguments

I have a (probably) quite uncommon problem.

Pseudocode:

```
\def\head{\titel } % \titel = undefined

\func{\head} % func is defined and handles \titel without any issues
\func{\titel} % throws an exception
```

It is neither a good idea to post the actual code (>3 pages) nor possible to reproduce it in an MWE. If I could reproduce it, I could probably solve it myself. I already tried `\unexpanded` and `\noexpand`.

What I want to get here: Hints what could be the reason of this problem. If requested, I can give you the whole code. But this will be at least two files.

---

Edit1:

*deleted, since no further useful information for the problem*

---

Edit 2:

This is the core function. It prints every token of `#4`. If any token is undefined it calls function `\GFM@<tokenWithRemoved'\'>`. Actually this function should work recursive, but then it throws an error at the inner function (since argument is undefined). `#4` may need double `{{ }}`.

```
\def\printLayout#1#2#3#4{{%#1=Liederbuch #2=Liednummer '#3=Liedvariante
    %
    %Definition of subroutines
    %
    \def\rest{\empty}%
    %
    \def\eaterB##1##2;{##2}%
    %
    \def\printer##1##2;{%
        \ifx##1\undefined%
            \edef\tempDefA{\expandafter\eaterB\string##1;}%
            \csname GFM@\tempDefA\endcsname%  !!!What will be called if undefined!!!
        \else%
            ##1%
        \fi%
        \edef\rest{\expandafter\unexpanded{##2}}%
    }%
    %
    %
    %Actual routine
    %
    \let\rest#4%
    \newif\iflooping%
    \loopingtrue%
    \loop%
        \ifx\rest\empty% 
            \loopingfalse%
        \else%
        \expandafter%
        \printer\rest;\relax%
        \fi%
    \iflooping\repeat%
}}
```

I decided to follow a different approach in this project. The Edit2 is for people with similar problems, who stumble over this question. You may, but dont need to resolve this problem.

Comment: `\def\head{\titel}` is fine, but without knowing what `\func` does we can't really help. Assuming `\head` is entirely free-form it's tricky to design a test for 'one or more undefined control sequences': we'll need some more spec.

Comment: @JosephWright func tests for each token of the argument, if it is undefined. If it is, it calls another function (`\GFM@<value1>@<value2>@<value3>@titel`; the values change). If it is defined, it is printed.

Comment: `\ifx\#1` won't work of course

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yep, you are right. :facepalm:

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it _works_ so long as you want to test if `\#` is `\let` equal to `1` ....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, but that's not what is intended ;-)

Comment: also, was the space here intentional? `\def\func#1 {`

Answer (score 2):

You don't give much to go on, but this plain tex file shows the described behaviour, the first call works, the second gives an error.

```
\def\func#1{\expandafter\string#1}

\def\head{\titel } % \titel = undefined

\func{\head} % func is defined and handles \titel without any issues

\func{\titel} 


\bye
```

Comment: That is clearly understandable. Shall I append the actual code? But this will be huge. I appended my workaround, which doesnt work either though it definitely should.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz if it fits in the site limits and you really can not make it smaller then why not, but it has to be equivalent to the above, in the end, if you don't get an undefined command error by wrapping in one level of macro definition then expansion is being suppressed after one level of expansion, perhaps not exactly `\expandafter\string` but `\meaning` or `\detokenize` etc can have similar effect.

Comment: I decided (for several reasons) to follow a different concept which is much more simplified, but (a little) less easy to use. I will append the core def to the question, to help user who will encounter a similar problem.